# Java Lang NoSuchFieldError Releaseable References Manager

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm trying to implement [Scabbard](https://arunkumar9t2.github.io/scabbard/) to my project which is visualize dagger dependencies. I've followed the steps of its home page. but when I tried to build the project, it fails as shown below. I'll also add part of my Gradle. Actually, when I add the scabbard configuration part, it starts to fail. Implementation of other I guess doesn't cause this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.dev.arunkumar:scabbard-gradle-plugin:0.4.0"
    }
}
apply plugin: "scabbard.gradle"

scabbard {
    enabled true // default false
    outputFormat "svg" // default png
}
```

My error message is :

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: RELEASABLE_REFERENCE_MANAGER
    at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingDeclarationFormatter.<clinit>(BindingDeclarationFormatter.java:47)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.DaggerComponentProcessor_ProcessorComponent.getBindingDeclarationFormatter(DaggerComponentProcessor_ProcessorComponent.java:379)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.DaggerComponentProcessor_ProcessorComponent.getBindingGraphConverter(DaggerComponentProcessor_ProcessorComponent.java:383)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.DaggerComponentProcessor_ProcessorComponent.getComponentProcessingStep(DaggerComponentProcessor_ProcessorComponent.java:396)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.DaggerComponentProcessor_ProcessorComponent.getImmutableListOfProcessingStep(DaggerComponentProcessor_ProcessorComponent.java:486)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.DaggerComponentProcessor_ProcessorComponent.injectComponentProcessor(DaggerComponentProcessor_ProcessorComponent.java:634)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.DaggerComponentProcessor_ProcessorComponent.inject(DaggerComponentProcessor_ProcessorComponent.java:623)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor.initSteps(ComponentProcessor.java:105)
    at dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.init(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.init(incrementalProcessors.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.init(annotationProcessing.kt:170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ProcessorState.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:508)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:605)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:698)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1043)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1184)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:78)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:34)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:229)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:192)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:108)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:526)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:517)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:185)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:164)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1549)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


e: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: RELEASABLE_REFERENCE_MANAGER
```

Comment: Same problem, probably has to be reported on the scabbard project.